# asp.net getting different session values after setting a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    public class Login : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var jsonString = String.Empty;

            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            }

            User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonString);

            BusinessEntities.LoginSession ls = new BusinessEntities.LoginSession();
            ls = VerifyLoginCredentials(user.Username.Trim(), user.Password.Trim());

            context.Session["user"] = null;
            context.Session.Clear();

            if (ls.isValid)
            {
                context.Session["user"] = ls;
                context.Response.Write("1");
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Write("0");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("0");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

There are lot of users logs in to the system using this method. sometimes after login session takes another sessions value.

Lets say User A and B logged in and User A send a request to get the product details but User A getting results of User B. This is strange. do i done something wrong ?

EDIT

```
  public static BusinessEntities.LoginSession VerifyLoginCredentials(string username, string password)
    {
        return DAL.Creadentials.VerifyLoginCredentials(username, password);
    }

    public class LoginSession
{
    public bool isValid { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string NewId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PasswordLastResetDate { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Are you working with `static` variables somewhere in your normal pages?

Comment: Please post the code for VerifyLoginCredentials() and BusinessEntities.LoginSession.

Comment: @VDWWD all my data access and business methods are static

Comment: Just remember that static variables are the same for all users. So if you declare a static variable ShoppingCart to hold all the product then A and B are adding and removing in the same variable and will see each others products.

Comment: it is not always happening there are 1000 users loged in and randomly 1 or 2 is getting this issue. and session is not static. always am getting user id from session

Comment: you cant use static variables. it is shared among all users.